# Finding highest value in list in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, geocoding

I have a list of dates and EVI values and extracted the EVI values to find the highest one. However, when I iterate through the list, it won't print anything for the maxEViValue (every value in datatable is higher than -100). What's the problem?

This is my code:

```
// Initialize a variable to store the maximum EVI value
function findmaxEVI (){
    var maxEVIValue = -100; // Start with a very small value
    
    // Iterate through the datatable to find the maximum EVI value
    for (var i = 0; i < 132; i++) {
      var num = datatable.get(i);
      var eviValue = ee.List(num).get(1); // Get the EVI value from the sublist
      
      
      if (eviValue > maxEVIValue) {
        maxEVIValue = eviValue; // Update the maximum if a larger value is found
        print(maxEVIValue);
      }
    }
    

}
findmaxEVI();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the highest value from a list, I think you can do it very easily with a reducer. A max reducer will return the maximum value in your list.

```
var maxEVIValue=datatable.reduce(ee.Reducer.max())
```